# Expand UIButton when touching down in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uikit

When a user touches down on my `UIButton` subclass, I want the the button to expand in size outward. However, when I manipulate the button's frame in the touchDown event nothing happens.  The touchDown event is being called and I can change other properties such as color, but not the frame.

What is going on here?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {    
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {        
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    }  

    return self;
}

- (void)touchDown:(id)sender {
    self.frame = CGRectInset(self.frame, -20, -20);
}
```

**EDIT:** The button is nested deep within a view hierarchy, but each superview has `clipsToBounds = NO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my superview implements layoutSubviews and resets my subview frames each time I update their frame.

Answer (score 1):

instead of changing the frame, do something like:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (0.8, 0.8);
```

Comment: Hey Dancreek, I tried this but it only scales the content within the button. The actual button size is unaffected.

Comment: Are you sure?  Affine transform affects the whole button.

Comment: You're correct.  It does affect the whole button, but see my answer for the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this instead of the self.frame you have in the touchDown method above:

```
#define EXPAND_BY 5.0
[self setBounds:CGRectMake(-EXPAND_BY, -EXPAND_BY, 
                 self.bounds.size.width + EXPAND_BY * 2, 
                 self.bounds.size.height + EXPAND_BY * 2)];
```

Just make sure to put the bounds back, otherwise your button will keep expanding.

Comment: Take a look at CGRectInset(CGRect rect, CGFloat dx, CGFloat dy), a little cleaner.  Just use negative number for dx and dy to expand.  
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectInset